# install ssmtp in Debian buster

Tags: debian, ssmtp

I try to install `ssmtp` in Debian 10.0, but get the error

```
Package ssmtp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

But I get no result with neither `apt search ssmpt` nor:

```
$ apt-file search ssmtp
monitoring-plugins-basic: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssmtp
sosreport: /usr/share/sosreport/sos/plugins/ssmtp.py
```

How do I install ssmtp in Debian buster?

Comment: You can install it from yource, there are some old mirrors, e.g.
https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
apt install msmtp
```

[ssmtp](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP)

> Package is currently unmaintained
>
> This package has been orphaned since 2019-03-19. `msmtp` can be used as an alternative.

[debian wiki: msmtp](https://wiki.debian.org/msmtp)

[msmtp: documentation](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html)

[manpage msmtp](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/msmtp/msmtp.1.en.html)

Comment: nullmailer is another alternative (despite the name your emails do get delivered)

Comment: Does it have the same config structure?

Comment: Are you sure? ssmtp is a MTA and msmtp appears to be  a MUA.

Comment: Msmtp doesn't work like ssmtp :(

Comment: remember to install `msmtp-mta` as well, which symlinkslinks msmtp to sendmail

Answer (score 10):

ssmtp is currently unmaintained, but you can install and configure `msmtp` as well:

For gmail (with deactivated 2-factor login) use this configuration in `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
port 587
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
from <user>@gmail.com
auth on
user <user>
password <your password>

# Set a default account
account default : gmail
```

To test it run

```
echo -e "Subject: msmtp test\nhello test." | msmtp _recipient_address_
```

You should find your sent e-mail in the recipient's inbox shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t useful for Debian 10, but `ssmtp` [is available in Debian 11](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ssmtp).