# mail: Can't send message: process exited with a non-zero status

Tags: raspberry-pi, email, raspbian, ssmtp

Any idea why it is not sending mail for me? Am I missing something? I tried a few articles and it seems like I have done everything correctly; so I am a bit stuck on this?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

And in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf I have:

```
root=hidennBecausePrivate@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=hidennBecausePrivate@gmail.com
AuthPass=password
UseTLS=YES
```

I get this message when I enter this command:

```
echo "Hello world email body" | mail -s "Test Subject" hostname@gmail.com
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

Comment: I have no idea what is happening here, is there any verbosity argument you can pass to the failing program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install ssmtp in Debian buster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525235/install-ssmtp-in-debian-buster)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue on raspbian buster. It's deprecated and msmtp is recommended instead, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you clarify what changes OP needs to make in order to get in order to use your proposed solution?